# How to download an entire directory from Dropbox - snapshot from a given date?

Tags: dropbox

and sub-directories. Can it be done, or do I have to D/L each file individually?

I want to D/L the whole directory contents as it was on a given data (say, at midnight)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot download the snapshot version of a full directory, you will have to do so individually for every file.
[image]

Comment: aaaargh!!  How to suggest it to them?